# Connection was reset / file upload in asp.net azure with ssl only

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload a file to blob in asp.net azure. I am getting success if the page is without ssl. but if i upload with https page then i am getting connection was reset error.

```
    And also I mentioned the maxrequestlength in web.config.
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Do you have ASP.NET Web Role with HTTP and HTTPS endpoint? Please write detailed problem and also what is the size of blob you are trying to upload?

Comment: i have webrole with both http and https end points

Answer (score 0):

This is not Azure specific error instead it is an ASP.NET specific problem. I did some test if  I could hit the problem but no luck..

I am getting sure that the problem is introduced by adding maxrequestlength and potentially having request filtering. You must setup the timeout setting with length and support script runtime in webserver specific settings.

You also have one option to RDP to your instance and enable IIS debugging to understand what could be the problem: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26798

After running Debug Diagnostic Tool v1.2, please share your log, and i will look for root cause.

**To RDP Access to Windows Azure Application, [visit my blog here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/04/03/setting-rdp-access-in-windows-azure-application-with-windows-azure-sdk-1-3-1-4.aspx)**

Comment: Hi avkashChauhan How to install that tool in azure.I am using azure using azureportal only.No RDP nothing is there

Comment: You would need to add RDP access to your application and then redeploy your application. and Once you have RDP access enabled, you can RDP to your VM and do anything needed.